# Insert using loop in SQL query for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [Id] AS [SeatId]
  -- ignore seatId from the oringal table- it's not the true id, it's like a title
```

FROM [pointsebagothisticketcomdb].[dbo].[tb_Seat]
   WHERE [sectionID]  = 1 AND [RowId] = 'C'

-- for each id TO THIS

```
INSERT INTO [pointsebagothisticketcomdb].[dbo].[tb_Ticket]
           ([showTimeId]
           ,[SeatId]
           ,[Price]
           -- ,[notes] IGNORE [NOTES] I PLAN TO REMOVE IT FROM SCHEMA TODAY
           ,[reservedTime]
           ,[Identifier]
           ,[CreatedOn]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[ModifiedOn]
           ,[ModifiedBy]
           ,[IsDeleted]
           ,[IsSold])
     VALUES
           (<showTimeId, int,> -- @showTimeId
           ,<SeatId, int,> -- THIS IS THE alias SeatId (really [dbo].[tb_Seat].Id)
           ,<Price, decimal(10,2),> -- @price
           --,<notes, ntext,> IGNORE [NOTES] I PLAN TO REMOVE IT FROM SCHEMA TODAY
           ,<reservedTime, datetime,>  -- @reservedTime
           ,<Identifier, uniqueidentifier,> -- AUTOMATICALLY ASSIGNED BY THE DB AS NEWGUID
           ,<CreatedOn, datetime,> --  AUTOMATICALLY ASSIGNED = CURRENT UTC DATE TIME
           ,<CreatedBy, nvarchar(50),>  -- SET = @CreatedBy  
           ,<ModifiedOn, datetime,>  -- AUTOMATICALLY ASSIGNED = CURRENT UTC DATE TIME
           ,<ModifiedBy, nvarchar(50),>  -- SET = @CreatedBy  
           ,<IsDeleted, bit,>  -- SET = 0
           ,<IsSold, bit,>)  -- SET = 0
GO
```

FROM FIRST QUERY I GET NUMBER OF ROWS LET SAY TWENTY ROWS NOW I WANT TO INSERT ACCORDING TO THAT ROWS SEATID
HOW CAN I LOOP ALL RECORDS ACCORDING TO IT?

Comment: DO NOT USE ALL UPPER CASE - IT LOOKS LIKE YOU ARE YELLING

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [pointsebagothisticketcomdb].[dbo].[tb_Ticket]
       ([SeatId]) 
SELECT [Id] AS [SeatId]
  FROM [pointsebagothisticketcomdb].[dbo].[tb_Seat]
  where [sectionID]  = 1 AND [RowId] = 'C'`
```